# Sony Xperia L won't turn on but it works well when I removed the SD card

Tags: sd-card, water-damage, sony-xperia-l

Help! My phone was recently repaired for water damage. It works fine but when I put my SD card in, it won't turn on (on the pick-up day). I went back to the shop and told them; they tried to put in their own SD card and it worked and they said that I needed to format my SD card. I formatted the SD card and still my phone won't turn on. The SD card works with other devices,e.g. Samsung Galaxy fit s5670, samsung slide phone, laptop. So, it's just my phone that doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score -2):

Try this formatter https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

The standard formatter integrated in windows isn't that great. Give it a shot. You can also try to set your phone back to factory settings after you did the format.